# Is the matplotlib draggable legend not available on Mac OS 10.8?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, legend

I have a small python program that takes in data and plots it using matplotlib (v1.3.x).  The plot has a draggable legend.  It renders fine on Windows, but I get an error on Mac (OS 10.8.3).  The code first creates a figure, then uses the figure to create a subplot, which returns an axes.  I'm using the axes object to create the legend.  Similar to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
lines = ax.plot([1,2,3,4])
legend = ax.legend(lines, loc=2)
legend.draggable()
plt.show()
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/legend.py", line 1007, in draggable
update=update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/legend.py", line 54, in __init__
use_blit=use_blit)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 1540, in __init__
DraggableBase.__init__(self, ref_artist, use_blit=use_blit)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/offsetbox.py", line 1462, in __init__
self.canvas = self.ref_artist.figure.canvas
AttributeError: 'DraggableLegend' object has no attribute 'ref_artist'
```

I haven't found anything on the web that can explain this error or why the draggable legend doesn't work on mac.  I did find this in the matplotlib documentation: `Note that not all kinds of artist are supported by the legend yet`, but I don't know if that applies here.

Can anyone help?

Comment: your code works on my linux machine with `1.2.1` version of matplotlib, which is the latest _stable_ release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work with the `osx` backend. This backend is still a bit experimental and it is missing several features (e.g. sub-pixel line widths). However, I've just tried and the draggable legend works with the `Qt4Agg` and `GTKAgg` backends. Perhaps you have one of these installed? You can switch backends in many ways:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

with ipython interactive:

```
ipython --pylab=qt
```

or even changing `.matplotlibrc`:

```
backend      : Qt4Agg
```

Comment: I have tried your options and can't get them to work.  For both the backends I'm getting errors about packages/modules not being installed (sip and pygtk).  After getting the errors I used macports to install both packages but it doesn't seem like my interactive python can find them.

Comment: @Crystal: if you're using MacPorts I recommend just getting the Qt4 backend -- I've used it extensively and works well in OS X. You need to install the qt4 variant of matplotlib, something like: `port install py-matplotlib +qt4`. MacPorts will then install PyQt, sip, and all the required packages.

Comment: OK... I've done that and I'm still getting the same error - it can't find the sip module.  I think my python is importing the wrong matplotlib.  I've checked to make sure I'm invoking the correct python, and it is.  I can see all of the matplotlib and Qt packages in the frameworks path (macports installed matplotlib v1.2.0), but when I import matplotlib within the interactive python and ask for the version I get v1.3.x.  How do I make sure it imports the correct package?

Comment: On further examination it looks like macports (or something) appended the correct paths to the pythonpath but since matplotlib is still in the previous path it finds v1.3.x first.

Comment: Finally got it working!  Uninstall v1.3.x and python found the right matplotlib.  Thanks!